# jQuery UI Autocomplete Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to perform some sort of text field validation before the Autocomplete request results for the inputted text. My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#vnu").autocomplete({
      source: "url",
      minLength: 1,
      delay:200,
      focus: function (event, ui) {
        $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
 <input type="text" name="vnu" id="vnu" />
</body>
```

So basically when someone enters text into the field, I want to check for a valid format before lettering Autocomplete request a results lookup. I already have a function written which return true all false, I am just not sure where to call it from.

Answer (score 5):

I have finally figured out a working solution for all those interested, you can use the search event to run any pre request actions/validation. See the search addition in the code below:

```
$(function() {
  $("#vnu").autocomplete({
    source: "url",
    minLength: 1,
    delay:200,
    focus: function (event, ui) {
      $(event.target).val(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    },
    search: function (event, ui) {
      return some_validation($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

Autocomplete search event reference: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-search